# JOINした際に重複するレコードの1つ目のみ値を返し、2つ目以降はNULLで返したい

Tags: mysql, sql

以下のような3つのテーブルがあります

| order_id_1 | order_value_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA |
| 2 | BBB |
| 3 | CCC |

| order_id_1 | order_id_2 | order_value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | JJJ |
| 1 | b | KKK |
| 2 | c | LLL |
| 2 | d | MMM |
| 3 | e | NNN |

| order_id_2 | order_id_3 | order_value_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | A | PPP |
| a | B | QQQ |
| b | C | RRR |
| b | D | SSS |
| c | E | TTT |
| d | F | UUU |
| d | G | VVV |
| e | H | WWW |

この3つをJOINさせて以下のような結果を得たいのですが、方法がわかりません

| order_id_1 | order_id_2 | order_id_3 | order_value_1 | order_value_2 | order_value_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | A | AAA | JJJ | PPP |
| <del>1</del> NULL | <del>a</del> NULL | B | <del>AAA</del> NULL | <del>JJJ</del> NULL | QQQ |
| <del>1</del> NULL | b | C | <del>AAA</del> NULL | KKK | RRR |
| <del>1</del> NULL | <del>b</del> NULL | D | <del>AAA</del> NULL | <del>KKK</del> NULL | SSS |
| 2 | c | E | BBB | LLL | TTT |
| <del>2</del> NULL | d | F | <del>BBB</del> NULL | MMM | UUU |
| <del>2</del> NULL | <del>d</del> NULL | G | <del>BBB</del> NULL | <del>MMM</del> NULL | VVV |
| 3 | e | H | CCC | NNN | WWW |

OUTER JOINをすると重複レコードが出てきてしまうのですが、1つのみ値を返し、2つ目以降はNULLを返すようにしたいと考えてています
(わかりやすいようにIDはNULLを返していませんが、ここも同様です)

この実装方法が分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: １つ目と２つ目以降を分けてクエリーし、それらを結合するのかなと思いました。ところで、１つ目・２つ目の定義は何でしょうか？ idの若い順？

Answer (score 1):

上の行と同じ値なら次の行の値をNULLにするというのは SQL 的考えでは邪道と思われます。いや邪道ですね。
SQＬの抽出結果は本来出力順を考慮せず、前後の行の値を比較しないので(Order Byを除く)、プログラム側で対処すべき要件と思います。

ただし MySQL8 ならウィンドウ関数が使えるので、以下のように[lag関数](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag)を使って前の行と同じ値ならnullを返すということもできそうです。

```
select 
    case when lag(order_id_1) over w = order_id_1 then null else order_id_1 end as order_id_1,
    case when lag(order_id_2) over w = order_id_2 then null else order_id_2 end as order_id_2,
・・・・・
from table1 inner join table2 ・・・
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

きっとひらぽんさんと同じことをやっているんだとは思いますが`ROW_NUMBER()`を割り出しておいて、それが`1`か否かで分岐とか。

```
SELECT
    CASE order_rank_1 WHEN 1 THEN order_id_1 END,
    CASE order_rank_2 WHEN 1 THEN order_id_2 END,
    order_id_3,
    CASE order_rank_1 WHEN 1 THEN order_value_1 END,
    CASE order_rank_2 WHEN 1 THEN order_value_2 END,
    order_value_3
FROM (
    SELECT
        order_1.order_id_1,
        order_2.order_id_2,
        order_3.order_id_3,
        order_value_1,
        order_value_2,
        order_value_3,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY order_1.order_id_1) AS order_rank_1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY order_2.order_id_2) AS order_rank_2
    FROM order_3
        LEFT OUTER JOIN order_2 ON order_3.order_id_2=order_2.order_id_2
        LEFT OUTER JOIN order_1 ON order_2.order_id_1=order_1.order_id_1
) AS X;
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！やってみます！